# SharePoint Online Site Collection Creation slow for Publishing Portal

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, publishing-site

Whenever I create a new site collection with the Publishing Portal template from the SharePoint admin center of Office 365 it takes 15 minutes or more to finish.

1. Is this normal for Publishing Portal Site Collection Creation?
2. Is there anything that I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Oder Identified the issue with this? I have the same problem, but only in one tenant.

Comment: @Sascha No, I've not been able to solve this issue.  I don't make site collections all the time so it's not the end of the world for me.  It's more of an annoyance since our previous on-premise SharePoint was much faster.